# R: Chaining seq and sort yields unexpected result

Tags: r, sorting, functional-programming, seq

I am trying to understand the (to me) unexpected behavior of chaining seq and sort:

```
> seq(sort(c(5,1)))
[1] 1 2
> sort(c(5,1))
[1] 1 5
> seq(1,5)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> seq(c(sort(c(5,1))))
[1] 1 2
```

I would expect, that the first line yielded a sequence from 1 to 5, as this is what I would like to get, but I cannot make R do this just by chaining these to functions. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to pass arguments to a function as a vector , you can use `do.call()`. It allows you to execute a function call with a function *name* and a *list* of its arguments.

```
do.call(seq, as.list(sort(c(5,1)))) # vector needs to be converted to a list
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Your example returns `[1] 1 2`, because whenever we pass `seq` a vector of length `> 1`, it will act as `seq_along`. In other words, a sequence will be created with a length equal to the count of elements in the vector.